# How to set currentTime in an <audio> file given hh:mm:ss?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, current-time

I've got 2500 transcripts with time stamps every 3 minutes. I want the time stamps to jump to the time in the audio file.

I'm using Javascript and HTML5 and have the code pieces working but not the whole thing.

```
<script>
function initAudio(){
    var speedlist = document.getElementById("speedlist");
    speedlist.addEventListener("change",changeSpeed);

function changeSpeed(event){
    myAudio.playbackRate = event.target.value;
                   }
function setCurrentTime(event){
    myAudio.currentTime = event.target.value;
                   }
function hmsToSecondsOnly(str) {
    var p = str.split(':'),
        s = 0, m = 1;
    while (p.length > 0) {
        s += m * parseInt(p.pop(), 10);
        m *= 60;
    }
    return s;
}
            }
window.addEventListener("load", initAudio);
</script>
<font size="2px">&nbsp;&nbsp; .5 x
<input id="speedlist" type="range" value="1" min="0.5" max="2.5" step="0.1" width="100px"> 2.5 x&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>
<img title="Reset Audio Speed to 1 x" src="https://pocketcollege.com/Speed.png" onclick="myAudio.playbackRate = 1"></p>

<audio id="myAudio" controls preload="metadata" style="width:100%;"> 
<source src="https://pocketcollege.com/mp3/RR100A1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<input type="button" value="[3:13]" onclick="myAudio.currentTime=200">

<input type="button" value="[6:27]" onclick="setCurrentTime(hmsToSecondsOnly('6:27'))">
```

The first button works and moves the time to 3 minutes 20 seconds. The second button has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

So I got it to work. I had to separate out the hmsToSecondOnly function and change how I called it:

```
<script>
function initAudio(){
    var speedlist = document.getElementById("speedlist");
    speedlist.addEventListener("change",changeSpeed);
function changeSpeed(event){
    myAudio.playbackRate = event.target.value;
                   }
function setCurrentTime(event){
    myAudio.currentTime = event.target.value;
                   }
            }
window.addEventListener("load", initAudio);

function hmsToSecondsOnly(str) {
    var p = str.split(':'),
        s = 0, m = 1;

    while (p.length > 0) {
        s += m * parseInt(p.pop(), 10);
        m *= 60;
    }

    return s;
}
</script>

<input type="button" value="[6:27]" onclick="myAudio.currentTime=hmsToSecondsOnly('6:27')">
```